# iOS determine if user is not moving for a specific time

Tags: ios, location

I'm trying to create an app that will detect if the car stopped for 5 minutes, if it stopped for 5 mins, functionA will be called. What would be the best idea to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `CoreLocation` to track location events, so the delegate is called everytime there is a location event. What you can do is to create a `NSTimer` of 5 minutes that will trigger functionA, and the trick is to restart the timer when you receive a location update. That means the function will be triggered only if there wasn't location changes in 5 mins

Comment: i am having a problem on the delegate. is it normal that it sends update even i'm not moving?

Comment: i'm using this delegate - (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

Comment: @AldrinEquila that's probably due to low accuracy, the GPS is just trying to get a better accuracy so it calls the delegate every time the accuracy changes. Just filter the events by accuracy. Something like this `location.horitzontalAccuracy <= 5;`

Comment: what happen is, it resets the time even though i'm not moving

Comment: Don't restart the timer unless the accuracy is good enough to have it into account. You're probably indoors, GPS is not good enough for indoors. If you want to use your app for indoors, you should use `MotionData` instead of `CoreLocation` and restart the counter when you detect a movement

Answer (score 0):

1. Update the current location every 5 minutes.
2. Save the current latitude and longitude
3. Compare the latitude and longitude from your previous update.